# attribute contains exact number selector so 3 is found but not 13 or 23

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, selector

In a form there is a section that shows groups of 4 weeks in each div. See the code below

```html
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="1,2,3,4"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="5,6,7,8"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="9,10,11,12"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="13,14,15,16"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="17,18,19,20"></div>
... This continues until it reaches 
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="49,50,51,52"></div>
```

I have a code that grabs the current week by the variable `weekno` so `console.log(weekno);` returns today: `3`

I want to add a class `current` to the `.form-check` that has `weekno` in it's data-attribute `data-weeknr`.

So I tried to use the attribute contains selector instructions, but I need it to go deeper than these instructions allow.

```
$links = $(".formplate .form-check[data-weeknr*='3']");
console.log($links.length);
```

Because the above jQuery code will return in the console the number `7` due to the fact it now grabs every `.form-check` that has a 3 init. So it grabs not only 3 but also 13,23,[30,31,32],[33,34,35,36],[37,38,39],43 making the total of 7 groups.

So how can I change this line to do 2 things:

`$links = $(".formplate .form-check[data-weeknr*='3']");`

How to incorporate the variable `weekno`, how can I properly escape so that the var is allowed?
And how can I make it select only the number 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The esiest way for selecting only the one with a value of `3` is to add the separator as well to the start and end of the data attribute, like

```
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr=",1,2,3,4,"></div>
```

Then take for selecting the separators into the search, because `data-weeknr*` seaches for a string somewhere in the data attribute.

```
$links = $(".formplate .form-check[data-weeknr*=',3,']");
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using `$.inArray` . So, you can use `split(",")` this will give you array
then compare if the `week` value is there inside array if yes add class there.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var week = '11';
var count = 0;
$(".form-check").each(function() { //loop through form check
  var data_ = $(this).data('weeknr').split(","); //get array using split
  //check week is in array
  if ($.inArray(week, data_) !== -1) {
    count++;
    $(this).addClass('current') //add class
  }
})
console.log("Length --" + count)
```

```css
.current {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="1,2,3,4">A</div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="5,6,7,8">B</div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="9,10,11,12">C</div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="13,14,15,16">D</div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="17,18,19,20">E</div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="49,50,51,52">F</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created the below example code for the fulfillment of your requirement:

```js
var weekno = "3";
$(".form-check").each(function() {
    var dataWeeknr = $(this).attr('data-weeknr');
    if (dataWeeknr.indexOf(',') > -1) {
      var dataWeeknrArr = new Array();
      dataWeeknrArr = dataWeeknr.split(",");
      if(dataWeeknrArr.includes(weekno)) {
          $(this).addClass('current');
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="1,2,3,4"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="5,6,7,8"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="9,10,11,12"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="13,14,15,16"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="17,18,19,20"></div>
<div class="form-check" data-weeknr="49,50,51,52"></div>
```